# Multiple grid.appScope calls when used in cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass an id and get the corresponding details via web api call. I'm passing the id through ng-grid cell-template, but I keep getting the error:

10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

After this, the screen becomes unresponsive.
I've looked at this link here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3753, but no help. I have barely 4 records that have to be fetched, yet it goes into an infinite loop!

Below is my code:-

part of my controller:-

```
$scope.callContactService = function (creatorId) {
            var CreatorName = "";
            strFactory.getById(creatorId).then(function (currentUser) {
                CreatorName = currentUser.Result.FirstName + " " + currentUser.Result.LastName;
                $scope.operationTasks.CreatorName = CreatorName;

            });
            return $scope.operationTasks.CreatorName;
        };

        $scope.gridViewMyTasks = {
            enablePaginationControls: false,
            enableGridMenu: true,
            paginationPageSize: pagingConfig.pageSizes[0],
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
            columnDefs: [
                            {
                                name: 'CreatorName',
                                displayName: 'Creator Name',
                                cellTemplate: "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'>{{grid.appScope.callContactService(row.entity.CreatorName)}}</div>",
                                enableColumnMenu: true,
                                visible: true
                            }]}
```

the web api method being called:-

```
   getById: function (userId) {

                    config = {
                        params: {
                            userId: userId
                        }
                    };
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    $http.get(api/details/getById ,config)
                        .success(function (data) {
                            deferred.resolve(data);
                        }).error(function (response) {
                            if (response.Message){
                                sharedScopeStorage.store('errorMessage', response.Message);
                            }
                            else{
                                sharedScopeStorage.store('errorMessage', userNotificationConfig.get_user_error_message);
                            }
                            deferred.reject(response);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck with this since days!

Comment: any resolution to this problem?